# CSS - "slide-out" animation on <li> visibility change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a web page with a navigation bar along the top, consisting of an `<ul>` element holding inline `<li>` elements. I'd like to designate two of these list items to "slide out" when clicked, revealing additional list items.

Right now, I'm doing this by including the additional items as `<li>` elements which are hidden at page load. A click event bound to the two list items toggles the visibility of those additional elements. This solution works fine, but I'd like to make things pop a little more and have these additional list items slide in and out of the list horizontally, like a drawer.

I read into the `transition` CSS property, but it seems like they're tied to specific CSS properties - which would mean that a sliding animation would require a change in position, which I'm technically not doing right now. Is that correct, or is there a trick I can use to get that sliding animation?

Thank you!

Comment: Any code to work with  ? Maybe CSS ? What is wrong exactly ?

Comment: You can't `transition` the CSS `display` property. You'll need to use javascript/jquery.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to change the position or margin of your li.

Comment: You might want to look into `overflow` and `transform: translate` to accomplish this. The `translate` is much better than the position or margin animation, and it doesn't _technically_ move your element, just _visually_.

Comment: Thanks - I think jQuery's toggle() or show()/hide() functions should give me what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You could animate those li items through CSS when they have a certain class, which you would add to the element after the buttons were clicked, like this:

CSS:

```
/* default behavior */
li li {
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

/* slide out */
li.active {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").on("click", function(e){
        $(e.target).find("li").toggleClass("active");
    })
});
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/0vy8emam/7/